# How can I combine the forward-pipe operator with an anonymous function

Tags: r, function, anonymous-function, chaining, magrittr

Is it possible to combine the forward pipe operator with an anonymous function?
If so then how can i go about it?

I get that the basic idea is to pass arguments in a sequential manner for the functions to execute.Like below,first the anonymous function calculates the sum then passes it on to the factorial function.

How can I do the same
This is what I am trying to execute using the forward-pipe operator-

```
calculate <- function(func,d)
 {
   func(d)
   }

factorial(calculate(function(x){x+1},7)) # function x is the anonymous function
```

My code using the forward-pipe operator-

```
7 %>% calculate(function(x){x+1}) %>% fact()
```

the expected result is 40320, but it results in

> Error in func(d) : could not find function "func"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to call `calculate`'s arguments explicitly using name

```
7 %>% calculate(func=function(x){x+1}) %>% factorial()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `%>%` the argument (in your case `7`) is plugged in as the first argument of the preceeding function. Thus, `7 %>% calculate(function(x){x+1})` actually evaluates to `calculate(7, function(x){x+1})`.

You can fix this with

```
7 %>% calculate(function(x){x+1}, .) %>% factorial()
```

or with named arguments as then `7` is matched to the remaining argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the native pipe `|>` and anonymous function `\(x)` operators introduced in R 4.1.0 (May 2021):

```r
calculate <- function(func,d) func(d)
7  |> calculate(func=\(x) x+1) |>  factorial()
#> [1] 40320
```

You could also use it in one line, without defining `calculate`:

```r
7  |> {\(x) x+1}() |>  factorial()
#> [1] 40320
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>